# SumProduct #VALUE error array formula - trying to use "--"

Tags: excel

So .. i tried to use

```
={SUMPRODUKT(($F$3:$F$84=$N4)*($G$2:$L$2=O$3)*$G$3:$L$84)/2}
```

this cant handle if one of the values in the last range G3:L84 happens to be a an letter

so i have done some reading .. and if it was a matrix i should be able to use"--" double negating.. 
this is how ever not working

```
={SUMPRODUKT(--($F$3:$F$84=$N4)*--($G$2:$L$2=O$3)*--($G$3:$L$84))/2}
```

It still works unless i have values not existing

Comment: are you sure that `SUMPRODUKT` is not `SUMPRODUCT`? sounds very german to me :D also, may try: `{=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(($F$3:$F$84=$N4)*($G$2:$L$2=O$3)*$G$3:$L$84,0))/2}`

Comment: yes sorry translating everything from Danish - and it is working :) - THANK you  - submit as answer - so I can accept it ... if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that does **not** need to be committed as an array formula, i.e. with `CSE`.

Secondly, try:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($F$3:$F$84=$N4)*($G$2:$L$2=O$3)*N(+$G$3:$L$84))/2`

in which `N` is used to convert any non-numerics within the range `G3:L84` to zeroes whilst leaving any numerics unchanged.

Regards

Comment: If i use that I get ZERO  - but on the upside no error if I have numbers... but result is always 0

Comment: And the numbers within the sum range are actual numerics, not e.g numbers stored as text? And you copied my formula correctly, including the all-important unary plus preceding the range $G$3:$L$84, i.e. +$G$3:$L$84 and not simply $G$3:$L$84?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way, if you want to use array formulas (@XOR LX is right, that you do not need to commit the `SUMPRODUCT` formula as an array formula), you could us `SUM` and nested `IF` functions, like

```
={SUM(IF($F$3:$F$84=$N4,IF($G$2:$L$2=O$3,$G$3:$L$84)))/2}
```

Remember to commit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I think you'll need to take the division outside the SUM, i.e. =SUM(IF($F$3:$F$84=$N4,IF($G$2:$L$2=O$3,$G$3:$L$84)))/2, otherwise you'll get an error just as the OP does when there are text entries within the range G3:L84, since you'll be attempting to perform division on those text entries.